# JQuery nested if / else if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, nested

I have three input field in a page, they appear (.append) in different combinations and there is a fourth div that shows the sum of that combination: it could be: **a** (is always on), **a+b**, **a+c**, **a+b+c**. I'm using **if/else if** statement but idoesn't work for **a+b+c**. Can someone help? thanks.
The code i'm using:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".page").on("change keyup keydown paste propertychange bind mouseover", function(){

    var iva4 = $("#total_amount").val();
    var iva22 = $("#total22_amount").val();
    var iva0 = $("#total0_amount").val();

    if (($("#total_amount").length) && ($("#total22_amount").length)) {

        var totaleIva = (parseFloat(iva4) + parseFloat(iva22));

    } else if (($("#total_amount").length) && ($("#total0_amount").length)) {

        var totaleIva = (parseFloat(iva4) + parseFloat(iva0));

    } else if ((("total_amount").length) && ($("#total0_amount").length) && ($("#total22_amount").length) ) {

        var totaleIva = (parseFloat(iva4) + parseFloat(iva22) + parseFloat(iva0));
    }

    $("#totale-somma").val(parseFloat(totaleIva).toFixed(2));


    if( !$.trim( $('.subtotale').html() ).length ) {
        $('#somma-finale').css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $('#somma-finale').css("display", "block");
    }


   });

   });
```

Comment: please share html code also and elaborate your problem in more details.

Comment: are `total_amount`, `total22_amount` and `total0_amount` are getting created dynamically? and is there possibility that any of them may not be present in html DOM?

Comment: [@Bhushan Kawadkar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/649504/bhushan-kawadkar) Yes, the divs are added dynamically. Yor solution works perfectly.

Comment: Great!!, happy to help you. Could you please accept the answer if you find this solution helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order of the `if` blocks

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".page").on("change keyup keydown paste propertychange bind mouseover", function () {

         var iva4 = $("#total_amount").val();
         var iva22 = $("#total22_amount").val();
         var iva0 = $("#total0_amount").val();

         if ((("#total_amount").length) && ($("#total0_amount").length) && ($("#total22_amount").length)) {

             var totaleIva = (parseFloat(iva4) + parseFloat(iva22) + parseFloat(iva0));
         } else if (($("#total_amount").length) && ($("#total22_amount").length)) {

             var totaleIva = (parseFloat(iva4) + parseFloat(iva22));

         } else if (($("#total_amount").length) && ($("#total0_amount").length)) {

             var totaleIva = (parseFloat(iva4) + parseFloat(iva0));

         }

         $("#totale-somma").val(parseFloat(totaleIva).toFixed(2));


         if (!$.trim($('.subtotale').html()).length) {
             $('#somma-finale').css("display", "none");
         } else {
             $('#somma-finale').css("display", "block");
         }


     });
 });
```

Comment: `totaleIva` variable must be defined outside `if/ else` otherwise `$("#totale-somma").val(parseFloat(totaleIva).toFixed(2));` give you error.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar not required... javascript doesn't have block scope.. except for `let`

Comment: [Arun P Johny](http://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) Thanks for you answer, it works. I accept your answer, but i think i will use [@Bhushan Kawadkar] code because seems a step forward respect to my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all total fields will be available in html DOM, below is the solution to calculate total -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".page").on("change keyup keydown paste propertychange bind mouseover", function(){
        // below code will convert values to float otherwise to 0
        var iva4 = parseFloat($("#total_amount").val()) || 0;
        var iva22 = parseFloat($("#total22_amount").val()) || 0;
        var iva0 = parseFloat($("#total0_amount").val()) || 0;

        var totaleIva = iva4 + iva22 + iva0;

        $("#totale-somma").val(parseFloat(totaleIva).toFixed(2));


        if( !$.trim($('.subtotale').html()).length ) {
            $('#somma-finale').hide();
        } else {
            $('#somma-finale').show();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks [Bhushan Kawadkar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/649504/bhushan-kawadkar). [Arun P Johny](http://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) answered my question, but i will use your code, i give you a +1